# Does background noise play a part in the Alien being able to hear you?

Tags: alien-isolation

If there is already a lot of background noise, due to machinery or an alarm for example, will walking or running, (instead of crouching), still give me away?

Answer (score 3):

No... it is my understanding that the same ongoing noises do not have an effect an the xenomorph's senses, no matter how loud they are, however any thing activated by you or inevitably triggered by the level design will alert the xenomorph to your location... Also FYI... your motion tracker also alerts the xeno when he's close by so use it sparingly :D